# Corrupted image if variable is not static

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm doing the following:

```
static GLfloat vertices[3][3] = 
{    
    {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0, 0.0, 0.0}
};

glColor4ub(255, 0, 0, 255);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 9);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```

This works ok:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41764/posts/Screen%20shot%202010-03-28%20at%2020.04.56.png

However, if I remove `static` from vertices and therefore re-create the data on the stack on each rendering, I get the following:

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/41764/posts/Screen%20shot%202010-03-28%20at%2020.06.38.png

This happens both on the simulator and on the device.

Should I be keeping the variables around after I call `glDrawArrays`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason you're seeing weird results is because you're not drawing what you think you are.

```
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 9);
```

This means draw 9 vertices, hence 3 triangles. You only have 3 vertices declared in your array, so what the other 2 triangles will end up being is anybody's guess. You can see in the second picture that you indeed have more than 1 triangle... The data it ends up using is whatever else is on the stack at that time.

glDrawArrays does transfer on call, and  I *seriously* doubt the iPhone would not be compliant on this. It's really basic GL, that (I believe) gets tested for conformance.

Comment: Of course, you are right. Apologies for not spotting that. I would delete my answer if I could (but it is still the accepted answer).

Comment: Gah! What a red herring. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You are rendering uninitialized data in *both* cases. It just happens to look correct in the `static` case.

The third parameter to `glDrawArrays` is the number of *vertices* (which should be `3` in your case because you are trying to draw a single triangle).

You already told the GL that you are specifying 3 `GLfloat` per vertex (the first parameter of `glVertexPointer`). So the GL can figure out the total number of `GLfloat` to expect.

This should work:

```
GLfloat vertices[3][3] = 
{    
    {0.0, 1.0, 0.0},
    {1.0, 0.0, 0.0},
    {-1.0, 0.0, 0.0}
};

glColor4ub(255, 0, 0, 255);
glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
glVertexPointer(3, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);
glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
```